# How can I handle the mouse wheel click event in WPF?

Tags: wpf, click, mousewheel

I want to close a tab in my tab control when the mouse wheel is clicked.  How can I capture this event in WPF?

EDIT:
Here's the code:

```
private void tabMain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Middle && e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Middle button clicked");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mousewheel is actually the MiddleButton, So the condition for  Wheel click on a MouseDown event is ***ChangedButton == Middle && ButtonState ==  Pressed***

Comment: Is there a reason to check for `ButtonState == ButtonState.Pressed` in **`MouseDown`** event? Or it was just a copy/paste from somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

An even easier solution

> if (e.MiddleButton) {     MessageBox.Show("Middle button clicked"); }

Comment: in wpf? MouseButtonEventArgs.MiddleButton is an enum. cant convert to bool.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is trying to catch this event but fails, **check if sender has mouse gestures** "intercepting" and handling it before it reaches MouseDown event.

Here is my situation with HelixViewport3D from HelixTookit library. MouseWheelDown is caught in MouseDown event only after i nullify following gesture:

```
myHelixPort.PanGesture2 = new MouseGesture(MouseAction.None);
```

Hope it'll save you some time.