# Is there a right-click and scrollwheel click control for a button? C#

Tags: c#, right-click

Okay, I know this is a stupid question, but I can't find it in the controls. Is there a Right-Click and a scrollbutton click control for a normal button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For mouse right click check this:

```
 private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
      if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
        // Do something
        //...
      }
    }
```

For scroll button click check this: [Mouse Wheel Event (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479284/mouse-wheel-event-c)

Comment: you can make this as answer.. :)

Comment: I have to wait for 2 more minutes, otherwise I would have already. EDIT: 2 minutes have past.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right click event in C#. But if you want to show some custom items when right click is done, this is possible in jQuery.

To disable the right click menu with jQuery for the page as a whole do this:

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

To do it for just a particular element do this:

```
$("#myid").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

To show a custom menu, you have to define a class and then change the bind function as follows.

```
#menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {

    $('#menu').css({
        top: e.pageY+'px',
        left: e.pageX+'px'
    }).show();

    return false;

});
```

Following line is required  for closing the menu when the page is clicked or the menu clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu').click(function() {
        $('#menu').hide();
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
        $('#menu').hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: +1 for the web version. Unlucky for you this was a untagged winform question but lucky for future asp.net visitors...

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use this post for [rightclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776911/how-to-create-a-right-click-context-menu-for-a-button-in-wpf) and for [scollbuttonclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426232/how-can-i-make-wpf-scrollviewer-middle-click-scroll)
I guessed that you used WPF? Your question didn't mention anything about what you are using.